# how to setup bootstrap form in a modal

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to setup a angular modal with a bootstrap form. I do not understand why it is turning out the way it is. I am using a ngEkathuwa Lg modal with Angular-ui tabs inside. There is a huge space between the labels and input fields. I have a plunkr setup, for some reason the modal is not the actual width of mine. the buttons on mine are within the modal. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F0zaj74DqkFKzVU60VAs?p=preview)

```
<div class="col-md-6 column">
   <!-- Text input-->
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jobNumber">Number</label>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="jobNumber" name="jobNumber" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
</div>!
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Modal window adjust its width with respect to your window. This is an ideal situation. In case you want to customize it, set your own width for modal-content class

Comment: K, good to know. Do you know why there is such a big space between the labels and inputs

Comment: I see, you are using form-group class, it adds a marging-bottom of 15px, that is why you see big gaps between your form-group

Comment: that is actually ok, what I am wanting to change is the distance between the label and its specific input field .

Comment: I made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565188/how-to-change-the-distance-between-bootsrap-label-and-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have a few container class holding it open,  and if you put your 'job' and 'customer' on the top they won't be responsive.

If you use xs, sm, md , lg  ect.. like

```
class="col-sm-3"
```

you can account for the different device sizes.

**Here's your forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WEJlyWN8BTysMm4ES2qu?p=preview)**